# Unable to duplicate PyTorch's Neural Transfer example

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

I'm following the tutorial from [PyTorch's Neural Transfer](http://pytorch.org/tutorials/advanced/neural_style_tutorial.html). However, after downloading the Jupyter notebook and running it, I don't get the output as expected. Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Observed output.

[image: Observed Output]

Expected output.

[image: Expected Output]

It should be noted that I'm in the following environment with no CUDA support (on a Mac laptop).

- conda 4.5.0
- python 2.7.17
- jupyter 4.4.0
- pytorch 0.3.1
- torchvision 0.2.0

I did notice that the observed output is 128x128 and the expected is 512x512 (although, this observed difference is likely coming from the setup of using CPU or GPU).

The output of the observed style transfer looks like the following.

```
Building the style transfer model..
Optimizing..
run [50]:
Style Loss : 351316.375000 Content Loss: 53.188274

run [100]:
Style Loss : 318270.687500 Content Loss: 51.054543

run [150]:
Style Loss : 627803.375000 Content Loss: 59.788795

run [200]:
Style Loss : 351316.375000 Content Loss: 53.188274

run [250]:
Style Loss : 318270.687500 Content Loss: 51.054543

run [300]:
Style Loss : 627803.375000 Content Loss: 59.788795
```

And the expected output looks like the following.

```
Building the style transfer model..
Optimizing..
run [50]:
Style Loss : 0.147848 Content Loss: 0.470452

run [100]:
Style Loss : 0.043477 Content Loss: 0.343297

run [150]:
Style Loss : 0.035841 Content Loss: 0.315429

run [200]:
Style Loss : 0.031865 Content Loss: 0.306764

run [250]:
Style Loss : 0.030837 Content Loss: 0.302101

run [300]:
Style Loss : 0.030777 Content Loss: 0.299595
```

Comment: Have you tried redownloading the notebook and trying again, just in case some code was accidentally changed?

Comment: I've just downloaded it right now.

Comment: Try running it again - there is always an element of randomness in ML. In the meantime, I'm going to try it myself and see if I can reproduce your results.

Comment: I'm running the model now, and I'm getting the right loss values, nothing at all close to your values. Though, I'm running the `.py` version of the file, not the `.ipynb`, and although they should be identical, that might be the source of the problem.

Comment: I can confirm that running the `.py` file works and the losses shown are close to the documentation. Thanks for that!

Answer (score 0):

The output image looks like the results I had when I did not clamp the output image before saving it.